# RSS feed for deleted posts and comments

Tags: feed, customization, routing

I need to create a feed (RSS or Atom) of posts and comments that have been deleted (ie moved to Trash).

What's the best way of doing this? Right now I'm thinking about creating 2 pages templates containing a SQL / $wpdb query that returns posts and comments with trashed status (and then creating new pages eg deletedposts / deletedcomments)

Any better ways? Main reason for doing it this way is easy routing - ie the URLs are created for me. How would I handle the routing if I put this in a plugin and don't create pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want a feed it would be logical to create a feed, rather than emulate it with page.

`add_feed()` ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L62) ) and your queries+output in callback.

Comment: Ah - ok, that's exactly what I was looking for - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest thing to do is create a category called Trash and move your posts there; then you've got an automatic post and comment feed without a plugin or custom queries and with a slug of Trash.

Comment: But then I'd need to filter out that category in every loop / query in the rest of the site